# Run NUnit tests in VS2010 and Log the results

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nunit

How can i run my NUnit test cases in VS2010 and save the results in some text or excel file?
I did tried using NUnit test Adapter in VS2012, but that will only run the test and show the results in Test Explorer window. What i need that the same testing i can do in VS2010, but also log the results in some file

Answer (score 0):

Actually, one way how to do it is to build your test cases in .dll file and used [NUnit GUI runner](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=download) where you can add VS project or simply add .dll with your test cases and run your tests. After them there is simple option to save results to XML structure in Tools->Save Result as XML...

Nunit GUI runner also provides some other funcionality to run tests.